# Update ocLazyLoad links with the revised links created by grunt-rev

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am using yeoman (angular-fullstack) for my project. I want to use ocLazyLoad ([link](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)) in it with grunt-rev. But how do I update the asset links written in the js files by the new filenames created by grunt rev ? The links in the html file are update but how do I update the links in js file?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably be using usemin to perform the swapping of filenames in your specified files. So your usemin config might look something like this:

```
usemin: {
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      'dist/js/libs'
    ]
  },
  js: ['dist/js/config.lazyload.js']
}
```

Say your rev'd scripts are in dist/js/libs, then the above config will replace all references in config.lazyload.js with the rev'd filenames.

You'll probably have something already in your usemin config for doing the swap in your html files.